# primefaces ,eclipselink, data table after insert doesnt show the @joincolumn

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, primefaces, entity, glassfish-3

Data table after i inserting and there is a blank field that doesnt show the entity
since i can't post image here is the url

[after insert](http://postimg.org/image/g7k5ws0gh/)

after i reload / refresh the page the empty field is back to normal
[after refresh](http://postimg.org/image/t089wpc29/)

this is my entity

> @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
>       @JoinColumn(name = "c_kodegl", referencedColumnName = "c_glkode", insertable = false, updatable = false)
>       private Glaccms0 glaccms0;

im using netbean 7.3 , glassfishserver 3.1.2 and primefaces 3.5

any help?
here is my method save

```
    public List<Ksrekening> create() {
    System.out.println("masuk create");
    HttpSession session;
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    String servernamesku = (String) session.getAttribute("servernameuserdb");
    String username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
    String ipaddress = (String) session.getAttribute("ipaddress");
    EntityManager emku = getEntityManager();
    Date ddate = new Date();
    try {
        EntityTransaction trx = em.getTransaction();
        trx.begin();
        Ksrekening simpanKsrekening = new Ksrekening();
        simpanKsrekening.setCDstatus(cdstatuscreate);
        simpanKsrekening.setCKodecur(getSelected().getMscurrency0().getCKodecur());
        simpanKsrekening.setCKodegl(getSelected().getGlaccms0().getCGlkode());
        simpanKsrekening.setCRekening(crekeningcreate);
        simpanKsrekening.setCStat(cstatcreate);
        simpanKsrekening.setCTipe(ctipecreate);
        simpanKsrekening.setDtUser01(ddate);
        simpanKsrekening.setDtUser02(ddate);
        simpanKsrekening.setNLimit(nlimitcreate);
        simpanKsrekening.setVcKeterangan(vcketerangancreate);
        simpanKsrekening.setVcStation01(ipaddress);
        simpanKsrekening.setVcStation02(ipaddress);
        simpanKsrekening.setVcUser01(username);
        simpanKsrekening.setVcUser02(username);
        em.persist(simpanKsrekening);
        trx.commit();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Proses Insert", "Berhasil"));
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("Master Rekening Berhasil di simpan !"));
        current = new Ksrekening();
        TypedQuery<Ksrekening> query =
                em.createNamedQuery("Ksrekening.findAll", Ksrekening.class);
        List<Ksrekening> results = query.getResultList();
        return results;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Proses Insert", "Gagal"));
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("Master Rekening Gagal di simpan"));
        return null;
    }
}
```

method retrieve data on table

```
public List<Ksrekening> getKsRekeningList() {

    TypedQuery<Ksrekening> query =
            em.createNamedQuery("Ksrekening.findAll", Ksrekening.class);
    List<Ksrekening> results = query.getResultList();
    return results;
}

public void setKsRekeningList(List<Ksrekening> ksRekeningList) {
    this.ksRekeningList = ksRekeningList;
}
```

this is my data table xhtml

```
  <h:form id="form">
                <p:dataTable id="ListKsRekening"
                             value="#{MasterRekening.ksRekeningList}"
                             rowKey="#{item.CRekening}"
                             selection="#{MasterRekening.selectedKsrekening}"
                             selectionMode="single"
                             rows="25"
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                             paginator="true"
                             var="item" widgetVar="itemTable"
                             emptyMessage="Tidak Ada Rekening dengan Kriteria tersebut"
                             filteredValue="#{MasterRekening.filteredKsrekeningList}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputPanel>
                            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="itemTable.filter();" style="width:150px" />
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:column  id="kolomRekening" filterBy="#{item.CRekening}"
                               headerText="Rekening" footerText="Kode Rekening"
                               filterMatchMode="contains"  >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.CRekening}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  id="kolomKeterangan" filterBy="#{item.vcKeterangan}"
                               headerText="Keterangan" footerText="keterangan Rekening"
                               filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.vcKeterangan}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  id="kolomCKodegl" filterBy="#{item.CKodegl}"
                               headerText="Kode Gl" footerText="Kode GL"
                               filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.CKodegl}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  id="kolomketeranganckodegl" filterBy="#{item.glaccms0.vcGlket}"
                               headerText="Keterangan Gl" footerText="Keterangan GL"
                               filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.glaccms0.vcGlket}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  id="kolomtipe" filterBy="#{item.CTipe}"
                               headerText="Tipe" footerText="Tipe"
                               filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.CTipeTampil}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  id="kolomcurrency" filterBy="#{item.CKodecur}"
                               headerText="Currency" footerText="Kode Currency"
                               filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.CKodecur}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  id="kolomlimit" filterBy="#{item.NLimit}"
                               headerText="Limit" footerText="Limit"
                               filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.NLimit}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  id="kolomstatus" filterBy="#{item.CStat}"
                               headerText="Status" footerText="Status"
                               filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.CStatTampil}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  id="kolomjurnal" filterBy="#{item.CDstatusTampil}"
                               headerText="Masuk jurnal" footerText="Jurnal"
                               filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.CDstatusTampil}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton id="viewButtons" value="Edit" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                                         update=":displayedit :form:ListKsRekening" oncomplete="carDialogedit.show()"
                                         action="#{MasterRekening.parsing(MasterRekening.selectedKsrekening)}" />
                        <p:commandButton id="deleteButtons" value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                                         update=":displaysdelete :form:ListKsRekening" oncomplete="carDialogsdelete.show()"
                                         action="#{MasterRekening.parsing(MasterRekening.selectedKsrekening)}" />
                        <p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"
                                         update=":displayview" oncomplete="carDialogview.show()"/>
                        <p:commandButton id="createButtons" value="Create" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                                         update=":displaycreate :form:ListKsRekening" oncomplete="carDialogscreate.show()"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

this is my dialog for create

```
<h:panelGrid id="displaycreate" >
                <p:dialog id="dialogscreate" header="Create Rekening" widgetVar="carDialogscreate" resizable="true"
                          showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" >
                    <h:form id="dlgFormcreate">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputLabel value="Kode Rekening" for="CRekening" /></td>
                                <td>: <h:inputText id="CRekening" value="#{MasterRekening.crekeningcreate}" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputLabel value="Keterangan" for="vcKeterangan" /></td>
                                <td>: <h:inputText id="vcKeterangan" value="#{MasterRekening.vcketerangancreate}" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputLabel value="Limit" for="NLimit" /></td>
                                <td>: <h:inputText value="#{MasterRekening.nlimitcreate}" id="NLimit" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Kode Currency :"  /></td>
                                <td>:
                                    <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{MasterRekening.current.mscurrency0}"  panelStyle="width:350px" converter="#{converterMScurrency}"
                                                      effect="fade" var="kdcura" style="width:160px"  filter="true"
                                                      filterMatchMode="startsWith" >
                                        <f:selectItems  value="#{MasterRekening.mscurrency0List}" var="kdcur"
                                                        itemLabel="#{kdcur.vcKetcur}" itemValue="#{kdcur}"/>
                                        <p:column>
                                            #{kdcura.CKodecur} - #{kdcura.vcKetcur}
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Kode GL"  /></td>
                                <td>:
                                    <p:selectOneMenu   value="#{MasterRekening.current.glaccms0}" panelStyle="width:350px" converter="#{converterGlaccms0}"
                                                       effect="fade" var="p" style="width:160px"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                                                       >
                                        <f:selectItems  value="#{MasterRekening.glaccms0List}" var="player"
                                                        itemLabel="#{player.vcGlket}" itemValue="#{player}"/>
                                        <p:column>
                                            #{p.CGlkode} - #{p.vcGlket}
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Tipe " /></td>
                                <td>:
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{MasterRekening.ctipecreate}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Kas" itemValue="1" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bank" itemValue="2" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Credit" itemValue="3" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Status  " /></td>
                                <td>:
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{MasterRekening.cstatcreate}" id="CStat" >
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Aktif" itemValue="A" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tidak Aktif" itemValue="D" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Masuk Jurnal  " /></td>
                                <td>:
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{MasterRekening.cdstatuscreate}" >
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ya" itemValue="*******J**"  />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tidak" itemValue="**********" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hanya Saldo" itemValue="********R*" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <p:commandButton value="Create" oncomplete="carDialogscreate.hide()"  update=":form:ListKsRekening"
                                                     actionListener ="#{MasterRekening.create()}" ajax="true" process="@all" id="create"  >

                                    </p:commandButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </h:form>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

this is my update dialog and when i update the data table doesnt create a null value

```
 <h:panelGrid id="displayedit" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
                <p:dialog id="dialogedit" header="Edit Rekening" widgetVar="carDialogedit" resizable="true"
                          showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" >
                    <h:form id="dlgFormedit">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputLabel value="Kode Rekening" for="CRekening" /></td>
                                <td>: <h:inputText id="CRekening" value="#{MasterRekening.crekeningedit}" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputLabel value="Keterangan" for="vcKeterangan" /></td>
                                <td>: <h:inputText id="vcKeterangan" value="#{MasterRekening.vcketeranganedit}" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputLabel value="Limit" for="NLimit" /></td>
                                <td>: <h:inputText value="#{MasterRekening.nlimitedit}" id="NLimit" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Kode Currency :"  /></td>
                                <td>:
                                    <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{MasterRekening.selected.mscurrency0}"  panelStyle="width:350px" converter="#{converterMScurrency}"
                                                      effect="fade" var="kdcura" style="width:160px"  filter="true"
                                                      filterMatchMode="startsWith" >
                                        <f:selectItems  value="#{MasterRekening.mscurrency0List}" var="kdcur"
                                                        itemLabel="#{kdcur.vcKetcur}" itemValue="#{kdcur}"/>
                                        <p:column>
                                            #{kdcura.CKodecur} - #{kdcura.vcKetcur}
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Kode GL :"  /></td>
                                <td>:
                                    <p:selectOneMenu   value="#{MasterRekening.selected.glaccms0}" panelStyle="width:350px" converter="#{converterGlaccms0}"
                                                       effect="fade" var="p" style="width:160px"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                                                       >
                                        <f:selectItems  value="#{MasterRekening.glaccms0List}" var="player"
                                                        itemLabel="#{player.vcGlket}" itemValue="#{player}"/>
                                        <p:column>
                                            #{p.CGlkode} - #{p.vcGlket}
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Tipe : " /></td>
                                <td>:
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{MasterRekening.ctipeedit}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Kas" itemValue="1" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bank" itemValue="2" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Credit" itemValue="3" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Status : " /></td>
                                <td>:
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{MasterRekening.cstatedit}" id="CStat" >
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Aktif" itemValue="A" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tidak Aktif" itemValue="D" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Masuk Jurnal : " /></td>
                                <td>:
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{MasterRekening.cdstatusedit}" >
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ya" itemValue="*******J**"  />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tidak" itemValue="**********" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hanya Saldo" itemValue="********R*" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <p:commandButton value="Edit" oncomplete="carDialogedit.hide()"  update=":form:ListKsRekening"
                                                     actionListener ="#{MasterRekening.update()}" id="update"  >
                                    </p:commandButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </h:form>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

i think my problem is located at here

```
 <p:selectOneMenu   value="#{MasterRekening.current.glaccms0}" panelStyle="width:350px" converter="#{converterGlaccms0}"
                                                       effect="fade" var="p" style="width:160px"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                                                       >
                                        <f:selectItems  value="#{MasterRekening.glaccms0List}" var="player"
                                                        itemLabel="#{player.vcGlket}" itemValue="#{player}"/>
                                        <p:column>
                                            #{p.CGlkode} - #{p.vcGlket}
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

here

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "c_kodegl", referencedColumnName = "c_glkode", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Glaccms0 glaccms0;
```

and here

```
public List<Ksrekening> getKsRekeningList() {

    TypedQuery<Ksrekening> query =
            em.createNamedQuery("Ksrekening.findAll", Ksrekening.class);
    List<Ksrekening> results = query.getResultList();
    return results;
}

public void setKsRekeningList(List<Ksrekening> ksRekeningList) {
    this.ksRekeningList = ksRekeningList;
}
```

plus

```
                    <p:column  id="kolomketeranganckodegl" filterBy="#{item.glaccms0.vcGlket}"
                               headerText="Keterangan Gl" footerText="Keterangan GL"
                               filterMatchMode="contains" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.glaccms0.vcGlket}"/>
                    </p:column>
```

Comment: Your question is hard to read please edit and give proper information.

Comment: are you updating the table using ajax? can you show code of the managed bean?

Comment: i have updated my post, since i used primefaces its ajax update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is still hard to read.  All I can determine is that the item.glaccms0.vcGlket value is empty.  This indicates that the referenced glaccms0 entity is out of synch with what is in the database.  More information on how you are reading in this instance is needed, but my guess is you've created an instance, partially populated it and associated it to the new Ksrekening.  These are java objects - it will not get or reflect the data from the database unless you've read it from there.  Since the glaccms0 relationship is read-only, I'm not sure you've even set it in the code you've shown, and are likely populating the foreign key directly some other way, probably through a basic mapping.

If you do not set the relationship correctly with the object as read in from the EntityManager, you will have to rely on refresh to fix the relationship later on.

Comment: how to set relationship correctly? can i get it?

i am new to java, its still hard for me to understand how java works, since im from php with YII framework

Comment: thanks for the hint about relationship, i got it

my problem is because i just declare the relationship on one place as unidirectional relationship , and java called bidirectional relationship for my need

java is so great but hard to learn....

thanks